# How to add(show) context menu when I right click on NSTableView row?

Tags: swift, macos, contextmenu

I'm trying to show context menu from NSViewController with one tableView  instance.

```
...
lazy var contextMenu: NSMenu = {
  let rightClickMenu = NSMenu()
  rightClickMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Add card", action: #selector(addCard), keyEquivalent: "")
  rightClickMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Remove card", action: #selector(removeCard), keyEquivalent: "")
  return rightClickMenu
}()
```

Answer (score 2):

One of solutions:

```
...
override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(contextMenu, with: event, for: self.view)
}
...
```

Comment: @Moritz ok great